# Way to retrieve DocuSign account activation URL via API?

Tags: docusignapi

We're using the DocuSign API to integrate DocuSign functionality with our application. We are using the 21 CFR Part 11 compliance module, so we aren't able to do embedded signing.

During our process, we're creating a DocuSign account for the user based on the credentials they use to register for our application. However, currently they have to go outside of our system to their email to verify their DocuSign account, then they return to our app.

I'm curious if there's any way to retrieve that Account Activation URL for that specific user, so at least we could save them a trip to their email inbox and just show them the link so they could jump straight from our app to DocuSign to verify their account.

I'm thinking there may be some security holes there, so maybe this isn't even an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can create a unique account activation URL for user (don't think that's possible) but what you CAN do is use a DocuSign `Distributor` that does not have the verify email option set.

A `Distributor` is basically a "package" that lets you span new DocuSign accounts that have whatever settings you want set.  Within each distributor is an open that lets you skip the email verification part, that way you can create new users and accounts instantly and avoid the context-switch to email you're trying to avoid.

Only official DocuSign Partners have access to distributors (since a business relationship is required with DocuSign to span new accounts) but also for security reasons it's not available to all.  You'll need to reach out to your DS Account Manager to have your distributor modified and/or have a new one created.